# How to recover automatically month in a year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I would like to got the actual month,  the month -1, the month -2.  and the current month but with 1 year less

For example, I did this in my where :

```
      
where  extract(year from date) = 2021 or
extract(month from date) = 06
        orextract(month from date) = 07
      orextract(month from date) = 08

or  (extract(year from date) = 2020 and
    and extract(month from date) = 08)
```

But I would like to know how to do it automatically,  so I don't need change by myself every month.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and the expected result would help.

Answer (score 0):

So - it seems that you want this in a `where` clause, to filter rows by date. (Of course, "date" is a reserved keyword, so your column can't be called "date"; I will assume it's called `date_` with an underscore.)

You can do this as follows:

```
where date_ >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -14)
      and
      date_ <  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -11)
```

`trunc(sysdate, 'mm')` truncates the current date to the beginning of the month. Add -14 months moves back from 1 August 2021 to 1 June 2020 (14 months earlier). Add -11 months moves back to 1 September 2020; you want data strictly before 1 September 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter to when the date is :

- Before the start of next month and also equal-to-or-after two months before the start of this month; or
- Before the start of the month 11 months ago and equal-to-or-after the start of the month 12 months ago.

If you run it in August 2021 then you will get all dates from: June, July and August 2021 and August 2020.

Like this:

```sql
WHERE (   date_column <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  1)
      AND date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -2) )
OR    (   date_column <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -11)
      AND date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -12) )
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer but problem is that function trunc is not recognized per snowflake

Comment: @seb Your question is tagged as "oracle sql date" there is no mention of snowflake in your question or the tags so how are we supposed to know that you are using snowflake if you do not tell us? From a (very) brief search it appears that snowflake has a [`date_trunc` function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) so perhaps you could use that; or you could tag your question appropriately so that a subject-matter expert who knows about snowflake is able to see that you want an answer.